# OpenCL: Object not getting initialized with value

Tags: opencl

If I do the following:

```
this->bufferParams = cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, sizeof(Params), &params, NULL);
```

My buffer doesnt seem to get populated with my params object. However if I do this

```
this->queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(this->bufferParams, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(Params), &params, NULL);
```

Then it seems to work. Is there any way in the cl::Buffer syntax to initialize the params object directly rather than doing the enqueue command

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do this:

```
this->bufferParams = cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY|
CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(Params), &params, NULL);
```

If you don use the flag to copy from the host pointer it is not going to copy.
That pointer may be used for other things (like acquire memory) so you need to set the flag accordingly.

*EXTRA: Also, for very small structure objects, like your Params probably is, use it directly on `clSetKernelArgs()`. No need to create a buffer if you are just setting some constant values that are never written. It also goes trough a more optimized memory path.*

Comment: Okay..but from within the kernel, it should be fast access right? I will only do the above once

Comment: If you create a buffer, it behaves like a buffer, so it is a pointer in the kernel and can therefore be written. So it is not optimized in any way. However, if you declare it __constant the compiler will optimize it by using constant memory. But the simplest way is to just use `clSetKernelArgs()` directly. That already gives the compiler the hint that it will never be written, and avoids you to handle the buffer creation.

Comment: I'd recommend to use CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR to get better performance (zero copy if supported by the device). There are some requirements on Intel Gfx (buffer must be 4K aligned and length must be mul. of 64)